How to show checked list items collapsed by default in org-mode?
I'd like to
- [ ] show this
  - expanded

- [X] but keep this
  - collapsed

- [X] collapse
  this as well

on opening an org-mode file – is there any built-in config setting to do that?

First of all, I know of no built-in facility for this. But you can sort-of roll your own.
Assuming that the initial folding state is showeverything (the current default), then all you have to do is write a function that looks at every list item, and if its checkbox state is on, call org-cycle on it (or the function that org-cycle delegates to in this case: org-cycle-internal-local)1. Then you add the function to the mode hook: that way the function runs when you open the file.
Here's a a function that does that:
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
  (defun item-info (item)
    (let* ((typ (org-element-type item))
           (standard-props (org-element-property :standard-properties item))
           (pos (aref standard-props 0))
           (checkbox (org-element-property :checkbox item)))
      (list typ pos checkbox)))

  (defun toggle-fold-state (info)
    (when  (eq (nth 2 info) 'on)
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char (nth 1 info))
        (org-cycle-internal-local))))


  (defun org-cycle-x-checkbox-items ()
    (when (memq org-startup-folded '(nofold showall showeverything))
      (let* ((data (org-element-parse-buffer))
             (item-info (org-element-map data '(item) #'item-info)))
        (mapc #'toggle-fold-state item-info))))

#+end_src

and here's how to add it to the hook:
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'org-cycle-x-checkbox-items)

The function checks that the initial folding state is one of those that shows everything. If not, it does nothing: the list items are not showing in that case, so trying to fold them will actually backfire.
Some explanations
The main function is org-cycle-x-checkbox-items: it parses the buffer and then it calls org-element-map passing it the constructed parse-tree to apply a function, item-info on all list items. It then returns a list of the results of item-info, one for each list item.
item-info takes the item node as argument and queries it for three things that it returns in a little list of its own: the type of node (this is just debugging: it should always be item), the position in the buffer where the item begins and its checkbox state (on, off or `nil).
We then map toggle-fold-state over the list that org-map-element returned. For each element of that list which is a lisf of the three things above), toggle-fold-state checks the third element (note that nth counts from zero) and if it is on, it goes to the specified place in the buffer (the second element of that list) and calls org-cycle-internal-local which toggles the folding state - that's the function that org-cycle delegates to when you press TAB on the item.

Footnotes:
[1] Actually, that's not quite true. You really should only cycle the highest-level list item whose checkbox is on: any lower-level items under that item (remember, a list can contain sub-lists) should be left alone whether it has a checkbox or not and regardless of the checkbox state. But that's a more complicated program, so I have assumed above that (as in your example) there are checkboxes only at the highest level in a list. That's also the reason that I have assumed that the initial state must be one where everything is shown: if the headline that contains a list item with its checkbox state on is folded, then the list item is also hidden and cycling its fold state will reveal it. Again, you could do something about that at the price of a more complicated program.
